# Displaying validation messages in view (login)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

### The goal

Show validations' error messages in view if there are one.

### The problem

Actually, I don't know. Seems the application is just passing over validations from model.

### The scenario

My view, just for debugging proposals:

```
= debug @user.errors
```

(Yes, I'm going with HAML).

This is my authentication method (on model **/app/models/user.rb**):

```
[...]

def self.authenticate(email, password)
  user = find_by_email(email)
  if user && user.encrypted_password == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password,user.salt )
    user
  else
    nil
  end
end

[...]
```

This is my validation test (on **user.rb**'s model too):

```
validates :email, length: { maximum: 2 }
```

### Diagnose

The output in view is:

> [...]
>
> undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
>
> [...]

In other words, there's no `errors` method for `@user`. If I leave `@user` alone (without methods), the output is blank/null/empty/or whatever.

## And technically speaking...

I need to display some message in my view based on model's validations. How can I do this? Am I on the right way? And if so, what's wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do You obtain the @user variable?

Comment: The model provides me @user I guess.